# How to work around error while reshape data frame with spread()

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyr, spread

I am trying to transform long data frame into wide and flagged cases. I pivot it and use a temporary vector that serves as a flag. It works perfectly on small data sets: see the example (copy and paste into your Rstudio), but when I try to do it on real data it reports an error:

> churnTrain3 <- spread(churnTrain, key = "state", value = "temporary", fill = 0)
>   Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (169, 249), (57, 109), (11, 226)

The structure wide data set is relevant for further processing
Is there any work around for this problem. I bet a lot of people try to clean data and get to the same problem. 
Please help me
Here is the code:
**First** chunk "example "makes small data set for good visualisation how it supiosed to look
**Second** chunk "real data" is sliced portion of data set from churn library

```
library(caret)
library(tidyr)

#example
#============
df <- data.frame(var1 = (1:6),
             var2 = (7:12),
             factors = c("facto1", "facto2", "facto3", "facto3","facto5", "facto1") ,
             flags = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)) 
 df

 df2 <- spread(data = df, key = "factors" , value = flags, fill = " ")
 df2
#=============

# real data
#============
 data(churn)

 str(churnTrain)
 churnTrain <- churnTrain[1:250,1:4]
 churnTrain$temporary <-1
 churnTrain3 <- spread(churnTrain, key = "state", value = "temporary", fill = 0)

 str(churnTrain)
 head(churnTrain3)
 str(churnTrain3)
#============
```

Comment: Is the key unique? The error sounds like your key on your large dataset has duplicates in it.

Comment: If the data you have here works well, though it shows some structure of your data, it is a less-than-ideal example to give us for testing. Perhaps you should look at the rows indicated to see what is common about them that might cause a problem.

Comment: How to resolve the problem with key duplicates? Honestly I have no idea how to solve it. Just now I tried to work around with **reshape2** with dcast() and this one displays wornings and ahaves observations from 400 to 122.

Comment: the key = "state" has repetiions inside. If observation is in some stat then the flag marks under certain "state" so Florida can have couple of flags spread every couple observations, as well as any other state

Answer (score 0):

Spread can only put one unique value in the 'cell' that intersects the spread 'key' and the rest of the data (in the churn example, account_length, area_code and international_plan). So the real question is how to manage these duplicate entries. The answer to that depends on what you are trying to do. I provide one possible solution below. Instead of making a dummy 'temporary' variable, I instead count the number of episodes and use that as the dummy variable. This can be done very easily with dplyr:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)    
library(C50) # this is one source for the churn data

data(churn)

churnTrain <- churnTrain[1:250,1:4]

churnTrain2 <- churnTrain %>%
    group_by(state, account_length, area_code, international_plan) %>%
    tally %>%
    dplyr::rename(temporary = n)

churnTrain3 <- spread(churnTrain2, key = "state", value = "temporary", fill = 0)
```

Spread now works.

Answer (score 0):

As others point out, you need to input a unique vector into `spread`. My solution is use base R:

```r
library(C50)

f<- function(df, key){
  if (sum(names(df)==key)==0) stop("No such key");
  u <- unique(df[[key]])
  id <- matrix(0,dim(df)[1],length(u))
  uu <- lapply(df[[key]],function(x)which(u==x)) ## check 43697442 for details
  for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]) id[i,uu[[i]]] <- 1
  colnames(id) = as.character(u)
  return(cbind(df,id));

}

df <- data.frame(var1 = (1:6),
                 var2 = (7:12),
                 factors = c("facto1", "facto2", "facto3", "facto3","facto5", "facto1"))
f(df, key='fact')
f(df, key='factors')

data(churn)
churnTrain <- churnTrain[1:250,1:4]
f(churnTrain, key='state')
```

Although you may see a for-loop and other temporary variables inside the `f` function, the speed is not slow indeed.